# Nginx Disable Overwriting host to http_host

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, hostheaders

Nginx by default overwrites the $host property to $http_host if the http host header is present. Is there a way to disable this behavior?
I want to prevent host-header injection by disabling this behavior.

Comment: The value of `$host` is the same as `$server_name` before it is "overwritten" by `$http_host`. You could just use that instead.

Comment: Thanks @RichardSmith We are not setting the value for $server_name explicitly, so it will not be possible to use this approach currently. 
What i am looking for is some nginx variable which preserves the hostname from original request. Not sure if that is actually possible?